# latitude and longitude through a form in the datatype POINT

Tags: mysql, google-maps, point

I will insert the latitude and longitude through a form in the datatype POINT, but got error:

**Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field**

```
$user_ip = getenv(‘REMOTE_ADDR’);
$geo = unserialize(file_get_contents(“http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip”)); 
$latitude = $geo[“geoplugin_latitude”];
$longitude = $geo[“geoplugin_longitude”];
$coords = $geo[‘geoplugin_latitude’] .’,’. $geo[‘geoplugin_longitude’];
$coords = $latitude.$longitude;
$query .=  "point = '" . $coords . "',";
```

Any idea how to store the lat and lon the right way to the POINT column.

I think there must a conversion for the latitude and longitude with output like something as

```
0x0000000001010000001ac05b2041d84140e2cd757522766140
```

Comment: which kind of database?

Comment: mysql datatype is POINT

Answer (score 0):

The [**format for a POINT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_point) is:

```
POINT(x,y)
```

x is the longitude and y the latitude, so it has to be:

```
$query.=" point = POINT({$longitude},{$latitude}) ";
```

Comment: Thanks but error :    you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '},{$latitude})...........

Comment: Thanks , i try it for myself and this works fine. must find out why the sql is not good  $query.=" point = POINT({$latitude},{$longitude}) ";.....you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '},{$latitude})..(mysql beginner)

Comment: It must like this sample  $query .=  "ip = '" . $ip . "',";